# Integrate PayPal without API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to integrate paypal in my site but without using API beacause it needs to put API key APY sescret and and Username. In my case there are different vendors in my site and they are not supposed to share there API credientials to my site. so I need to accept payment using emailid only.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use Rest API, Adaptive Payments, or Express Checkout, which all use API Credentials, you can use PayPal Standard buttons. 
Below is a basic PayPal Add to Cart button example:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@youremail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sample Add to Cart Button">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

You can create a basic add to cart button in your PayPal account or you can use the [PayPal Button Factory](https://paypal.com/buttonfactory)
Here are the basics of PayPal Payments Standard:
[Basic PayPal Standard Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) 
[PayPal Standard HTML Variable Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)